# Template on Web content structure

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I've made a web content structure  which contain a field "Query_Title". The field Query contains sub fields : "Description" and "url".

I had to create a template for this new structure which is :

```
#if (!$Query_Title.getSiblings().isEmpty())
   #foreach ($cur_Query_Title in $Query_Title.getSiblings())
      $cur_Query_Title.getData()
  #end
#end
```

I would like to display every field : Title (as i already do) and Description and url as well, but i have no idea how to access them...
Any idea?

Comment: Can you share your structure xml? Also are these - `title`, `description` and `url` sub-fields inside `Query_Title`? Thanks

Comment: Finally i've used an ADT, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

`$cur_Query_Title` is of type TemplateNode, which is (beside some other functionality) a map that contains the sub fields:
`$cur_Query_Title.Description.data` and `$cur_Query_Title.url.data` should work for your example.